# ReactiveCocoa, How to obser the count of property of Array

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

assume that: 
a class Teacher have a array property students
and each student have a bool property finishedTask

how reactivecocoa work on it to cauculate the count of student that finishedTask

class like the following:

```
class Teacher: NSObject {
    dynamic var students: [Student] = []
}
class Student: NSObject {
    dynamic var finishedTask: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use reactivecocoa to observer array changes? if its a static array you could just use filter & count, no need to use reactivecocoa

Comment: yes, it's a dynamic array, may be this was the quick manner to do it